# How to calculate server compute for jitsi video calls

Tags: cpu-architecture, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I am using Jitsi for audio/video calls, I am able to access the bandwidth per call but I want to calculate the computation cost per call. Zoom is providing a subscription model and having a number of users limitations per call, and having price in place. I want to know how this multi-tenant application build and how to cost to them? Thanks in advance. I am using the AWS server only.